# What does “kind of edge” mean?

Tags: meaning

From Steinbeck's *Cannery Row*,

> If one of you fellas wants **to kind of edge** into my cellar without my wife seeing you, they’re on top of the side stringer on the left-hand side as you go in.

Comment: [Kind of](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/kind?q=kind+of#kind__15) + see [sense 2](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/edge) of the verb form of _edge_.

Comment: move or cause to move gradually or furtively in a particular direction?

Comment: Yes. "If one of you fellas wants to kind of **move furtively** into my cellar without my wife seeing you, ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One meaning of *edge* is to move slowly in gradual bursts.

That might be quite how one would best describe sneaking toward just far enough into the cellar to grab the objects referred to, which the "kind of" emphasises, it's often used when a speaker isn't confident in what they are saying.

Comment: Not sure *bursts* is quite the right word; it sounds too sudden and explosive, which is not fitting with a series of small, careful maneuvers. I would just call them *movements*.